# Get the scroll state of Listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

How can I get the scroll state of Listview?

I see the variable mTouchMode in class AbsListView which defines the scroll state, but it's not accessible.

I can listen to onScrollStateChanged and save the state in my class as well but really would like to reuse the existing mechanism and not add more code.

The reason I want the scroll state is to dynamically update a list ONLY when the list is idle and not being scrolled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening for `onScrollStateChanged` and keeping state in your subclass is the officially Google-blessed way to do this (see [API List demo 13](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html), which loads data in a list only if the list is done scrolling/flinging). Like most Android views, I think it's intended that apps use event-driven code rather than polling of view state, and giving access to the internal scroll state outside of that would encourage bad polling-type behavior from developers.